# jQuery selector using contains not working

Tags: jquery, contains, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to find all table cells containing "FieldName=".  I did this initially with getElementsByTagName and then looped through testing with indexOf and it works just fine, getting 191 cells and then successfully testing for my target cells perfectly.

I then tried it with $("td:contains('FieldName')"); and it fails.  I've tried backslashing the equals sign, double backslashing it and even removing it and I still get zero hits.  The case is correct as it works with indexOf without need for converting to UC or LC.

Help!  :-)  Seriously, standard JS works so I'll get by, but it's really frustrating to not be able to use such a cool tool and not know why.  Here's my code - comment and uncomment to see the result of both approaches:

```
//var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var cells = $("td:contains('FieldName\=')");
alert(cells.length);
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    if (cells[i].innerHTML.indexOf('FieldName=') > -1) {
        // do stuff here...
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'll feel silly when someone spots my mistake, but that's how we learn, eh? :-)

A sample cell:

```
        <TD valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="400px">
    <!-- FieldName="Title"
         FieldInternalName="Title"
         FieldType="SPFieldText"
      -->
        <span dir="none">
    <input name="ctl00$m$g_c2ed1f85_8eef_4759_817c_cd68435bd0a3$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$TextField" type="text" maxlength="255" id="ctl00_m_g_c2ed1f85_8eef_4759_817c_cd68435bd0a3_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" title="Title" class="ms-long" /><br>
</span>


    </TD>
```

Comment: Got the html handy? Helps speed things up :)

Comment: Also, mention the jQuery version you're using...

Comment: Post the HTML, that is the only way we are going to be able to solve this problem.

Comment: I'll post a cell, but the entire page is huge.  However, as I originally said, getElementsByTagName and indexOf get the job done...

Comment: Also, I should add that if I remove the contains, case does not matter - I get 191 cells whether I use td or TD, but if I add the contains, I get zip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem I see here is the difference between this line:

```
cells[i].innerHTML
```

and the way `:contains` works. `:contains` searches for a *text* string. It will ignore your HTML comments.

The reason innerHTML is working is because it returns *everything* as a String, `:contains` will only return a string found within the innerText of this element and child elements.

You could still use jquery in conjunction with plain JS to accomplish your goal like so:

```
$("td").each(function () {
    // var this is the current element's DOM object
    if (this.innerHTML.indexOf("FieldName") != -1) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Interesting!  No mention of that in the API.  Do you know an easy way to test HTML comments if they are not considered part of the text of a cell?

Comment: No problem, be sure to click the checkbox to the left if I best answered your question.

Comment: So there is no selector/subselector that will directly test the text of an element if the text is part of an HTML comment?

Comment: There is no built-in way to do this. However, a few plugins such as [this one](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1563-jQuery-Comments-Plug-in-To-Access-HTML-Comments-For-DOM-Templating.htm) allow you to query the DOM for comments... but I feel the method above is much more efficient. More plugins = more data to load = longer load times for user, especially if the benefit from the plugin is small.

Comment: I just incorporated it into my code and it works perfectly - again, thanks!  While it's obviously doing exactly what my original code using getElementsByTagName was doing, it's cleaner to read and understand for the next schmuck that has to maintain my code.

Comment: Yes it is, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work... remember contains is case sensitive, could that be your problem?

Is the html present at the time the javascript is executed?

Comment: This should have been written as a comment on the question, not as an answer. Answers are not meant for asking questions.

Comment: would have if i could have... new here